# How can I remove a button or make it invisible in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

How can I remove a button in Android, or make it invisible?

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Set button visibility to [GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) (button will be completely "removed" -- the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or [INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (button will became "transparent" -- its space will not be available for another widgets):

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or in xml:

```
<Button ... android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: when you set it to gone does it still count as a child? if i did something like child count or get child at index what ever?

Comment: I think yes, it does still count as a child.

Comment: And to show it like this.. b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Any way to enable/make it visible through javascript executor or anything?

Answer (score 40):

First make the button invisible in xml file.Then set button visible in java code if needed.

```
Button resetButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button_del);
resetButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //To set visible
```

Xml:

```
<Button
android:text="Delete"
android:id="@+id/my_button_del"
android:layout_width="72dp" 
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: I want make the button invisible, but that should be accesible in activity, much like Super secret button. It should not show up in activity, but the button should work

Comment: Use "buttonCleanup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" instead of the zero.

Answer (score 17):

To **remove** button in **java code**:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To **transparent** Button in **java code**:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To **remove** button in **Xml file**:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

To **transparent** button in **Xml file**:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 13):

This view is visible.

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But if you just want to make it invisible:

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

use setVisibility in button or imageViwe or ..... 

To remove button in java code:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
```

To transparent Button in java code

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```

You should make you button xml code like below:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

hidden:
         visibility: gone 
show:
        visibility: invisible
        visibility: visible

Answer (score 3):

```
button.setVisibility(button.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Makes it visible if invisible and invisible if visible

Answer (score 2):

IF  you want to make invisible button, then use this:

```
<Button ... android:visibility="gone"/>

View.INVISIBLE:
```

Button will become transparent. But it taking space.

```
View.GONE
```

Button will be completely remove from the layout and we can add other widget in the place of removed button.

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove a button from its parent layout:

```
((ViewGroup)button.getParent()).removeView(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activity_register_header"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

**Try This Code**

Visibility works fine in this code

Answer (score 0):

In order to access elements from another class you can simply use

```
findViewById(R.id.**nameOfYourelementID**).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your button invisible such that it doesn't take any space in the layout, then add this in your **Java code**:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Or in XML: `android:visibility="gone"`

If you want to make your button invisible such that it still takes up space in your layout then replace "View.GONE" with "View.INVISIBLE" in your **java** code or  replace "gone" with "invisible" in your **xml** code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(8);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try This Code :

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: you really shouldn't use hard-coded values in this method -- just use the Constants -- View.GONE, View.VISIBLE or View.INVISIBLE