# Set Button Visibility

Tags: android, button, visibility

I added a button in layout and obtained its reference in the activity:

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setVisiblity(View.Visible);
```

Program crashes with this code. How do I set its visibility correctly?

Comment: Can you provide details of how it is failing? I would guess that you're getting a NullPointerException which would indicate a problem with your XML layout file (i.e. no object defined with the ID "button1".)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a button or make it invisible in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127725/how-can-i-remove-a-button-or-make-it-invisible-in-android)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whats the error?  it should be `View.VISIBLE` (uppercase).

If you have a null pointer exception at that point, its probably because its not finding the view in your layout.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a nullpointer exception. I referenced the wrong object. That button's not in the current view

Answer (score 4):

the View.Visible should be in **UpperCase**  , so try this :

```
button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and if you aren't in the Activity and you want to change the Visibility , you should pass the Context of the Activity to that class in order to implement the method `Acitivity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable());`

Answer (score 3):

Steve,

Have you tried `View.VISIBLE` make sure the [`VISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) is in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using C# you can use

```
 button1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

I had the same problem originally.