# Hide/Show xml on android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a feature which hides/show .xml layout items similar to "javascript hide and show"? How do I accomplish this if the object is already stated inside of xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a button or make it invisible in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127725/how-can-i-remove-a-button-or-make-it-invisible-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the View's visibility. You need to define a listener to toggle [`View#setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) between the `VISIBLE` and `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Mind if I asked how would you go and do visibility on multiple objects in an an adapter? tested it and it worked beautifully on one piece but the rest is still showing.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code in your question? Talking about code is much harder than reading/writing actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```java
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/my_button"/>
```

Change button to whatever your element is you want to change the visibility of.

Comment: An upvote from me since this is the same answer and we answered at the same time.