# Hide AlertDialog's OK and Cancel buttons

Tags: android, dialog

I want to hide buttons from my AlertDialog. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465441/hide-buttons-in-dialogfragment-in-android) solution but it simply disables the buttons.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    ...
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    Button button = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setEnabled(false);

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the button's visibility to GONE instead of using `setEnabled()`. Also, you have to do this in the `onStart()` of your dialog like so:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
    if (d != null) {
        Button positiveButton = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button negativeButton = d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        positiveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        negativeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I want to say here is don't answer it in a third person perspective.