# Showing button part by part in Android

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

**Hi**

I am new in **android**. 
I have many `Buttons` in view in android and i want to show them part by part by clicking another button.

Comment: what is that `show them part by part by clicking`

Comment: for example firstly three of them and after clicking next button show next three buttons.

Comment: use VISIBLE , INVISIBLE  and GONE functions.

Comment: You mean like next, previous.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy i dont know how to write it i have writen code that make buttons dinamically. i need any idea

Comment: just see ans which is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote following code and solved my problem. maybe it might be useful to anyone
next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(i<movie_list.length-3)
            {
                movie_list[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                movie_list[i+3].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                i++;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That is the end of the buttons ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Set button visibility to [GONE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) (button will be completely "removed" -- the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) (button will became "transparent" -- its space will not be available for another widgets):

```
View b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or in xml:

```
<Button ... android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Ref By: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127725/how-can-i-remove-a-button-or-make-it-invisible-in-android/4127830#answer-4127830)

Comment: i did this code. next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
  next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    if(i<movie_list.length)
    {
     movie_list[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        movie_list[i+3].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        i++;
    }else {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That is the end of buttons ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
  });   but when i click next button after showing last button i get "app has stopped" error

Answer (score 1):

use `android:visibility="visible"` or `android:visibility="gone"` or `android:visibility="invisible"`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 1):

let say you have 2 buttons : in xml write this:Make button 2 invisible like below

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button 2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

In your oncreate method write this: when you click on button1 , button2 will appear.

```
     Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

1. **First make the above xml layout having all your buttons and set them to GONE because the buttons will not occupy space in the layout by default so saves you space and time at initialization.**
2. Now in your code on click event just set the visibility of these buttons to **VISIBLE**.

   **Steps for changing the visibility**
   HashMap map=new HashMap();
   map.put(R.id.button1,new Integer[]{R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4});

public void onClick(View v){

Integer[] buttonsToShow=map.get(R.id.v.getId());

if(buttonsToShow!=null)
   for(int button:buttonsToShow){

findViewById(button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
   }