# How to remove Button from layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have created multiple button in a layout dynamically.Now,i want to remove clicked button from layout.
for example:-[image][image][image]

Comment: onclick  of button make its visibility GONE

Comment: button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); will give empty space on the place of button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a button or make it invisible in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127725/how-can-i-remove-a-button-or-make-it-invisible-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick set `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: How to "Remove" button, not to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on every buttons you can get them all , then remove the activated ones

```
ArrayList<View> allButtons; 

//Get all buttons from the selected  layout, then put them in an arraylist
allButtons =((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.button_container)).getTouchables();

//loop on each button and remove the activated ones
foreach (Button b : allButtons){
    if (b.isActivated()){
        b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);

        parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
             });     
            b.setText("Primary");
            Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.your_image);
            image.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
            b.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, image, null);
            parent.addView(b);
        }
```