# List of recyclerView allows press buttons at same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I have a recyclerView list with buttons inside, one of these buttons do the exclusion of an item.

**The problem:**
my recycler allows clicking in two buttons of exclusion at the same time, crashing my app (because he tries to delete an item with a position that was updated).

So, I don't find a solution for this, maybe disabling the rest of the buttons in recyclerView when I do the event of click (but how to do this?). Has someone a solution?

**Sample:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVGT0.png

Comment: yes for disabling of any view ,you can set Visibility VISIBLE and INVISIBLE

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127830/8089770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your recyclerview

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```