# Change the visibility of a button on text change of a textView

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to change the visibility of a button to gone?

I have tried the following code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"                                
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_extra_larger"                                   
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="Amount" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="1"                               
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
    android:visibility='@={orderAmount.getText().equals("0.0") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}' />
```

I want to make the `clear_button` disappear when the text in the `order_amount` is "0.0".
I want to accomplish this using data binding expressions only.

Comment: This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127725/how-can-i-remove-a-button-or-make-it-invisible-in-android) might help you find the anwser

Comment: Your TextView *text* must be binded to your model (e.g. to a string called orderAmountValue), so the changes can propagate from one view to the other. Then, your Button can use this orderAmountValue property to execute your check. Without the binding Data Binding cannot detect the changes and notify other views.

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin:

```
clear_button.visibility = View.GONE //View.INVISIBLE
```

In Java:

```
clear_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Option 1: You need to call this method from wherever the TextView text is being set dynamically, so for instance:

```
//... something something something
order_amount.text = amount
if(amount == "0.0") clear_button.visibility = View.GONE
```

Option 2: Add a TextWatcher to your TextView programmatically, such as this (Kotlin):

```
order_amount.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
            if(text?.toString() == "0.0") clear_button.visibility = View.GONE
            else clear_button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    })
```

In Java:

```
order_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              //change visibility here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it using binding expression only.